# Docker NodeJS app cant connect to postgres database

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, nestjs

I am farely new to docker and docker-compose. I tried to spin up a few services using docker which contain of a nodejs (Nest.js) api, a postgres db and pgadmin. Without the API (nodejs) app beeing dockerized I could connect to the docker database containers, but now that I also have dockerized the node app, it is not connecting anymore and I am clueless why. Is there anything wrong with the way I have set it up?

Here is my docker-compose file

```js
version: "3"
services:
  nftapi:
    env_file:
      - .env
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - '5000:5000'
    depends_on: 
      - postgres
    volumes: 
      - .:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    networks:
      - postgres
      
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:latest
    ports:
    - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
    - /data/postgres:/data/postgres
    env_file:
    - docker.env
    networks:
    - postgres
 
  pgadmin:
    links:
    - postgres:postgres
    container_name: pgadmin
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    ports:
    - "8080:80"
    volumes:
    - /data/pgadmin:/root/.pgadmin
    env_file:
    - docker.env
    networks:
    - postgres
 
networks:
  postgres:
    driver: bridge
```

This is the nodejs app Dockerfile which builds successfully and in the logs I see the app is trying to connect to the databse but it cant (no specific error) just that it doesnt find the db.

```js
# Image source
FROM node:14-alpine

# Docker working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copying file into APP directory of docker
COPY ./package.json /app/

RUN apk update && \
    apk add git
# Then install the NPM module
RUN yarn install

# Copy current directory to APP folder
COPY . /app/

EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["npm", "run", "start:dev"]
```

I have 2 env files in my projecs root directory.

1. .env
2. docker.env

As mentioned above, when I remove the "nftapi" service from docker and run the nodejs up with a simple npm start it is connecting to the postgres container.

```js
TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'postgres',
      host: process.env.POSTGRES_HOST,
      port: Number(process.env.POSTGRES_PORT),
      username: process.env.POSTGRES_USER,
      password: process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
      database: process.env.POSTGRES_DB,
      synchronize:true,
      entities: ['dist/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
    }),
```

The host from the .env file that is used in the typeorm module is localhost

Comment: What address are you giving to connect postgres?

Comment: I edited the initial post inlcuding the way its trying to connect now

Comment: ok, but what is the value of POSTGRES_HOST?

Comment: its just "localhost" in a .env file so without quotes

Comment: It needs to be 'postgres'

Comment: wow Im actually stupid. I was naming the networks so they are all unified and then I just ignored it when connecting. Thank you very much, that did the trick!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using networks with docker-compose you should use the name of the service as you hostname.

so in your case the hostname should be `postgres` and not `localhost`

You can read more about at here:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/